# mysql select certain information and counts

Tags: mysql

Here is my Database structure

```
id, user_id, veh_id, amount
1, 2, 3, 123
2, 2, 4, 125
3, 1, 3, 122
4, 1, 4, 126
```

I am trying to get a SELECT to count for each user_id the number of time it as an amount for each veh_id.  If a user as no amount on a veh_id, I want to show 0 for that.

I am thinking of using SUM(IF()) but I don't know what to do to get them in a nice table all by user_id.

Here Is what I have so far

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(IF(user_id !=0, 1, 0)) AS COUNT
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY user_id
```

I'm I on the right track to get what I want

Here is my revised question, with the resutl beeing close to what I want:

Can I have a way to count the number of time a user was the highest bidder on a veh_id
So if a user place bid on 30 cars, I can see that he was 12 time the highest bidder

Comment: what does "to count for each user_id the number of time it as an amount for each veh_id" mean?

Comment: This is an auction system and this is the table where I store the bidding information from users.  Each user can bid amount on each veh_id and I want to know on how many vehicle each user placed a bid.  So for user X, he place bids on 26 out of 41 cars for example.  I would liek to have thoses 2 numbers  User Y place 33 bid out of 55 he was allowed to view.  This will be left join to other tables to get the dates

Comment: So I assume you have a vehicle table you are relating this to such that you have some means by which you can understand which vehicles a user does not have?

Comment: Your query seems to do what you wish? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d320/3, unless I misunderstood your question?

Comment: using the fillde, it seem to work but it only show me if I have activity for a vehicle, if I did not bid on a car, how can I ask the same SUM(IF ()) but find the cars where my user id is not present?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get cases where count = 0, you need to have a vehicle table that you can relate to this table.  Without this, you have no definitive way to understand what the universe of possible vehicles is. I also assume you have a table of users, as again without this, you don't know the full universe users.  You would need to join all three of these tables to get your answer.

For this example I will assume the table names are users, users_vehicles, vehicles

```
SELECT u.user_id, v.vehicle_id, COUNT(uv.id)
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN users_vehicles AS uv
   ON u.user_id = uv.user_id
RIGHT JOIN vehicles AS v
   ON uv.veh_id = v.veh_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, v.vehicle_id
```

Note that the `LEFT JOIN` between `users` and `users_vehicles` will include ALL `user_id` values, even if that `user_id` is not present in `users_vehicles`.  Similarly, the `RIGHT JOIN` between `users_vehicles` and `vehicles` will include all `veh_id` values even if they are not present in `user_vehicles`.

Comment: This is my actual real SELECT statement:  SELECT  ep.dealer_name, SUM(IF(eb.user_id !=0, 1,0)) AS Tentative, COUNT(e.id) 
FROM #__ezautos_bids AS eb
LEFT JOIN #__ezautos_profile AS ep ON ep.mid = eb.user_id
LEFT JOIN #__ezautos AS e ON e.id = eb.veh_id
WHERE e.listdate BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-07-31'
GROUP BY ep.dealer_name

Comment: the sum and count give me the same number.  I want to have 2 different numbers:  The number of time I bid on cars and the number of time I did not.

Comment: Perhaps, would be more simple if I even want 0.  So If a user did not bid, I get a 0 as the sum and therefore I don't need to know how many time user didi not bid.

Comment: Would there be a way to find out how many time the user as been the highest bidder in all the bid he place on each car

Comment: @maphaneuf I don't fully understand the mapping of the tables you mention in your comments to the tables I mentioned. You might try updating your original question with the actual table information and query being used, so it is clear what is going on. You could certainly form a query to find out the number of times a user was max bidder,and require the use of subqueries.  hard to day without really understanding the table structures.